# How to add focus using dynamic useRef on td on edit button click after setting contentEditable True

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I am creating here dynamic table, and I am trying to edit content of td on click of edit button click, so I am setting contentEditable true to each td on click of respective edit button, now i want to add focus by using useRed, but dynamic focus is not working, I refer other problems also on stackover flow, but nothing worked.

```
import react from "react";
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

export const Table = (props) => {
    const [contentEditableMode, setContentEditableMode] = useState(false)
    const [contentEditableId, setContentEditableId] = useState(null);
    const editTd = (e, id) => {
        console.log(e.target);
        console.log(id);
        setContentEditableMode(!contentEditableMode);
        setContentEditableId(id);
    }
    useEffect(() => {

    }, [contentEditableMode])
    
    
    return (<div><table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Title</td>
                <td style={{ "paddingRight": "20px" }}>Edit</td>
                <td>Delete</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            {props.tableData && props.tableData.map((row, ind) => {
                return (
                    <tr key={row.id}>
                        <td>{row.id}</td>
                        <td contentEditable={contentEditableId === row.id ? contentEditableMode : null} suppressContentEditableWarning='true'>{row.title}</td>
                        <td style={{ "paddingRight": "20px", "cursor": "pointer" }} onClick={(e) => { editTd(e, row.id) }}>Edit</td>
                        <td style={{ "cursor": "pointer" }} onClick={() => props.deleteRowData(row.id)}>Delete</td>

                    </tr>)
            })}
        </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>)

}
```

Comment: "But dynamic focus not working", you didnt show any new code indicating whats not working. Please just provide reproducible example, put the code in codesandbox.

Comment: you must provide reproduction of problem.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-shadow-7rh42s?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Here I give you just one example, how you can use `useRef` to focus on the edit queue, if you want `useRef` in `map` you have to be unique in the ref values must be added and when you click on the edit line the status will be checked to see if the id exists in `focusRef` then you have to check the console and check if the focus attribute exists, If you have a focus attribute, you can add focus to the edit line. Thanks

```
import React, {useRef} from "react";
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

export const Table = (props) => {
    const focusRef = useRef([]);

    const [contentEditableMode, setContentEditableMode] = useState(false)
    const [contentEditableId, setContentEditableId] = useState(null);
    const editTd = (e, id) => {
        if (focusRef.current && focusRef.current[id]) {
          console.log(focusRef.current[id])
          //focusRef.current[id].focus();
        }
        console.log(e.target);
        console.log(id);
        setContentEditableMode(!contentEditableMode);
        setContentEditableId(id);
    }
    useEffect(() => {

    }, [contentEditableMode])
    
    
    return (<div><table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Title</td>
                <td style={{ "paddingRight": "20px" }}>Edit</td>
                <td>Delete</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            {props.tableData && props.tableData.map((row, ind) => {
                return (
                    <tr key={row.id}>
                        <td>{row.id}</td>
                        <td contentEditable={contentEditableId === row.id ? contentEditableMode : null} suppressContentEditableWarning='true'>{row.title}</td>
                        <td ref={ref => (focusRef.current[row.id] = ref)} style={{ "paddingRight": "20px", "cursor": "pointer" }} onClick={(e) => { editTd(e, row.id) }}>Edit</td>
                        <td style={{ "cursor": "pointer" }} onClick={() => props.deleteRowData(row.id)}>Delete</td>
                    </tr>)
            })}
        </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>)

}
```